# ¿Como agregar scroll vertical a una tabla con el head y el footer fijo con CSS o style?

Tags: jquery, html5, css, bootstrap, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla, donde les coloco el ancho fijo a los head:

```
<table id="listado" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50px">Campo 1
        </th>
        <th style="width:50px">Campo 2 
        </th>
        <th style="width:54px">Campo 3
        </th>
        <th style="width:60px">Campo 4
        </th>
        <th style="width:32px">Campo 5
        </th>
        <th style="width:243px">Campo 6
        </th>
        <th style="width:114px">Campo 7
        </th>
        <th style="width:56px">Campo 8
        </th>
        <th style="width:132px !important">Campo 9 
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="9">

        </th>
</tfoot>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ></td>
    </tr>
  <tr><td></td>..........
 ......
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Lo que yo quisiera es agregar un scroll vertical desde un alto o heigth 250px con el header y footer fijo. He visto algunos ejemplos, pero no se adaptan lo que yo planteo.Me gustaría saber como agregar el scroll

Answer (score 1):

Prueba poner en el style

```
overflow: scroll;
```

URL del artículo: http://www.ejemplode.com/18-css/642-ejemplo_de_scroll_en_div_overflow.html
Leer completo: ejemplos de Scroll en div overflow

Comment: creo que no es tan simple como eso

Comment: Exactamente, no funciona así